# Регулярные выражения в Python. re.findall

Tags: python, строки

Допустим есть строка со списком файлов(по факту несколько тысяч имен):

```
lst='20201023_IVST_X_60-HXX_60.ASC 20201002_E502_XX_60-HXX_60.ASC 20201125_PETT_XX_60-HAE_60.ASC 20201112_E502_XX_60-HK2_60.ASC 20200815_E502_X_60-HAE_60.ASC 20201126_KLYT_XX_60-HAN_60.ASC'
```

Необходимо выбрать все имена содержащие `HAE`.

Пробовал так:

```
hae=re.findall('....................HAE....ASC', lst)
```

Однако имена файлов имеют разную длину потому работает не корректно. Как в регулярном выражении обойти это ограничение? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем тут регулярки?

```
lst='20201023_IVST_X_60-HXX_60.ASC 20201002_E502_XX_60-HXX_60.ASC 20201125_PETT_XX_60-HAE_60.ASC 20201112_E502_XX_60-HK2_60.ASC 20200815_E502_X_60-HAE_60.ASC 20201126_KLYT_XX_60-HAN_60.ASC'

for x in lst.split():
   if 'HAE' in x:
      pass # ...
```